# How is the correct way to disable an input type="image" using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

With jQuery, I'm trying to disable an input field like this:

```
<input id="submit" type="image" src="submit.jpg">
```

What I would like to do is disabling the button and change the image with a different image (submitGreyed.jpg) to visually notify that button is disabled.

With the following line I disable the button:

```
JQuery("#submit").attr('disabled','true');
```

then I change the image with:

```
JQuery("#submit").attr('src','submitGreyed.jpg');
```

and once disabled I submit the form with:

```
JQuery("#form").submit();
```

The second line has some weird behaviour; sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

When it works, button is disabled, image changed and form is submitted; 
when it does not work, button is disabled, form is submitted but image is not changed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: In what way does it sometimes not work? Do you mean it breaks in some browsers?

Comment: yes, it does not work in firefox 3.5.7 and safari too.
Once image appears for the first time, then it starts to work.
But, when i close and reopen the browser, it does not work again.

Comment: Your quotes are unbalanced between double and single quotes. #form is missing the end quote entirely

Comment: You are right, but it was just a typo.Source code is correct.

Comment: Have you tried not submitting the form at all? If it is something preloading will solve, then it should work every time if you comment out the submitting part to test for a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but I hope it helps:

First, it should be `disabled="disabled"` so use this:

```
jQuery("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

And I am not sure what your grayed out button looks like, but you could try just using opacity:

```
jQuery("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity',0.5);
```

**Update** I couldn't replicate the problem, so here is my suggestion:

Use an absolute path to the image instead of a relative one, and set both attributes at the same time (Though setting one after the other didn't change my test):

```
jQuery("#submit").attr({
   disabled: 'disabled',
   src:      '/images/submitGreyed.jpg'
});
```

Since in my test I used a full path, that might have affect it a bit.

[**View a demo here**](http://jsbin.com/owaja3)

Comment: `Disable: true` also works via jQuerry. I'm not sure if it's the browser or jQuery that accepts it. Probably the browser seeing the attribute with any value.