# action link image not getting disabled in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to disable the image link of edit using jquery in webgrid
my code is as follows.

```
grid.Column("Edit", format: id => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink("[Edit]", "myactionname", "mycontrollername", new { id = id.Id }, new { @class="edit"}).ToHtmlString().Replace("[Edit]", "<img src=\"/images/edit_icn.png\" ... />")))
```

my jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("inside function")
    $('.edit').attr("disabled", true);
    alert("outside function");``
});
```

But the link is not getting disabled.. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

[How is the correct way to disable an input type="image" using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211652/how-is-the-correct-way-to-disable-an-input-type-image-using-jquery)
you can check out this stack overflow link it is similar to your question,May be it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Go it working!!....
replaced my jquery code and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".edit").click(function () {
        return false;
    });

});
```