# jQuery disable continue button before filling all the fields

Tags: jquery

I want to disable the image button inside  the anchor tag using jQuery.
my requirement is, the button should be disabled before filling the all form fields.

```
<form name="signupFrm" id="signupFrm">
 <input type="text" />
 <a href ="javascript:void(0)" class="btnspc1 continueBtn submit"> <img src="images/continue-button.png" alt="jio money"/></a>
</form>
```

I tried in the following way, but no luck

```
$form = $('#signupFrm'); // cache
$form.find('a.submit img').prop('disabled', true); // disable submit btn
```

Comment: you can't disable a image... you need to check it in the click handler... but if you want to give a disabled look  and feel use a class

Comment: `disabled` is not a property of DOM images.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211652/how-is-the-correct-way-to-disable-an-input-type-image-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give the button a disabled look, you can use this CSS:

```
.disabled {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
}
```

and then apply the style to you button like so:

```
$('a.submit img').addClass("disabled");
```

and remove this like so:

```
$('a.submit img').removeClass("disabled");
```

Demo: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/teqoqi/embed?html,js,output)

Comment: I added a demo just now where you can type and see it disable or enable as you type

Answer (score 1):

there is no direct disabled option for an img,
you should program with 2 images, 1 with bit greyed color another with bright color
and you should program the click event to return false and preventDefault() like that

Duplicate: [Gray out image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286275/gray-out-image-with-css)

Duplicate: [How can I disable the color of an image using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262472/how-can-i-disable-the-color-of-an-image-using-css)

Duplicate: [How do you make an anchor link non-clickable or disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654900/how-do-you-make-an-anchor-link-non-clickable-or-disabled)